# guess charset encoding in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, curl, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to write my own web crawler with cURL in PHP.

```
[...]
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
$this->_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 0);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10');
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$header = array(
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
            "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
            "Keep-Alive: 115",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array());
curl_setopt($this->_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
$page = curl_exec($this->_curl);
[...]
```

The problem is the charset of the website. As you can see on

http://blog.163.com/drewes_4711/blog/static/179317021201151624826557/

there is a header `"Content-Type: ...;charset=GBK"` so I can do `mb_convert_encoding($content, "UTF-8", "GBK");` but what should I do with

http://tech.hexun.com/2011-06-21/130756909.html

It *seems* to be the same charset, but it's not given in HTTP header. So I have massive problems with german umlauts, chinese and asian languages... Is there any module or snippet that I can use to determine the charset of ANY downloaded HTML site with cURL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That second link contains:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
```

All data before that looks like plain ASCII. So you could try, if the HTTP headers don't give a clue, just parsing (assuming plain ASCII, not UTF-8 - that's likely to break) until you find that header.

This is obviously not guaranteed to work. If the server doesn't send the encoding, and the page doesn't have that header either, you're out of luck. There are no universal means to detect the encoding of a given piece of data.

Comment: @mu,@Mat: Great. I don't know, why I haven't looked for this on my own. But wouldn't it be right to assume that content is UTF-8 when I send `"Accept-Charset: utf-8"` and I cannot find any content type in header or content?

Comment: In an ideal world, you indeed wouldn't have this problem. But if your app only caters for well-configured, standards compliant web servers and pages... there's a lot of stuff you're going to be missing :-)

Comment: For sure. I'm going to try now to parse header and content for charset definition, after that I'll check with `mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8')`, else I'll do `utf8_encode($string)`